# is this the correct way to doc block a callable's output in php 8.2?

Tags: php, syntax, callable, docblocks, php-8.2

I would like to properly document a PHP 8.2 inline callable's output for an array of strings.

here's an example:

```
/** @var callable $params : Array<string> */
$params = fn() : array => array_map(
    $format(...),
    [
        $fieldId,
        $matchType->name,
        $value,
    ]
);
```

assuming `$format(...)` always returns a string, is this the correct syntax?